# How can I implement dynamic routing in Python?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, parameters, routes

I'm attempting to implement dynamic routing for a web framework. At the moment, the goal is to pass arguments into a function by way of the url. So, if user offers a url of "/page/23", then the route function will extract the "23" which will then be used as a parameter for the page function. I am getting a "keyerror", however.

```
import re
routing_table = {}
url = "/page/23"

def route(url, func):
   key = url
   key = re.findall(r"(.+?)/<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*>", url)
   if key:
      params = re.findall(r"<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)>", url)
      routing_table[key[0]] = [params, func]
   else:
      routing_table[url] = func

def find_path(url):
   if url in routing_table:
      return routing_table[url]
   else:
      return None

def page(page_id):
   return "this is page %d" % page_id

route("/page/<page_id>", page)
print(routing_table[url])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you called `route`, you used a `url` equal to `"/page/<page_id>"`, but in the last line, `url` is a global variable equal to `"/page/23"`.

It looks like there are other problems:  replace your last line with

```
print(routing_table)
```

to see what you're doing.

Comment: I did what you said, and deleted the global url variable, and printed(routing_table). When I print the last line, it shows: {'/page': [['page_id'], <function page at 0x0000000002C37E18>]}   So, I can see that the url key maps to a list containing the variable, and the function. But I'm not sure how to pass that variable into the function.